# Why is this javascript auto fill multiple fields not working?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm new to JavaScript and I can't figure out why this code isn't working.  I want to have the user input data at the meta input table and have them click [input] to input the data in all of the rows for each column, for instance if 12/22/2012 is put for born and input is clicked, all fields under 'born' should be filled for both male and female tables.  I copied the code for the html from the page into a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/hopup/h2jjd/3/

Any help appreciated, please remember I'm new to JavaScript so constructive criticism would be nice.

here is the Javascript

EDIT 2: Made some changes to my code, am I getting closer?  It still does not work.

EDIT 3:THis works on chrome, but not on firefox.  Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/hopup/h2jjd/5/ <-- check this one

```
function fill (colname) {
var numRows, i, toCopy, iterated_name;

numRows = document.getElementById('malesTable').rows.length + document.getElementById('femalesTable').rows.length - 2;
toCopy = document.getElementById(colname.id).value;
i = 1;
for (i; i <= numRows; i++){
    iterated_name = colname.id + "_" + i;
    document.getElementById(iterated_name).value = toCopy;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look in the JavaScript console it reports an `unexpected token ILLEGAL` in mausdb.js line 9. So I'd look there, perhaps run it through [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) to catch any other errors.

Comment: Yeah I see I get many errors, however what can I do to change the code to make it act as expected.  I guess it's illegal to use `count` where I did to try to call the value of each text field.

Comment: The problem is not with your JavaScript code, it is with the invalid characters in the source file, @hopup. Edit the file in a text editor and re-type the last line of that function, as well as the next couple of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
   document.myform.count.value = document.getElementByName(name);
```

seems to be the odd one. Three errors I've spotted:

- The code accesses the "count" property (a form element named "count") of the form. You seem to want `document.myform.elements[count]`
- There is only a `getElement/s/ByName` method, which returns a NodeList of elements. You might want to use ids, there is `getElementById()` to return only the one element with the unique id.
- the getElement-function returns a Node / an Element, not its content. So use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) or access the element's text nodes.

Comment: I want `count` to be the the name of each text field, as the amount of mice is generated on the previous page.  So say there are 3 males and 3 females.  external_id is the name of the input field on the bottom, and external_id_1 is the first external_id_2 is the second output field etc... which is why I add the "_" + i to the current name as it iterates.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the [bracket syntax](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#eId) does

Answer (score 0):

There are illegal characters in your JavaScript source file.

*edit* looks like a non-Western glyph, U+8B80 - 讀 The version you posted in the question is not the same, at least not exactly.

*edit* ah durrr it's UTF-8, not UTF-16 of course.  It's a zero-width space, as @Pumbaa80 points out. Oh, and specifically this is in the file [mausdb.js](http://nimml-dev.vbi.vt.edu/miepcms/static_pages/mausdb.js).

Comment: Nope, it's a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Really?  Well that would make a little more sense.  I see a E2 before the close curly brace, and then 8b 80.  Whatever; they're not going to make JavaScript happy whatever they are :-)

Comment: I don't know how these strange characters got into the code, Have i removed them in the edits?

Comment: @hopup it's in that "mausdb.js" file - that's the file that's causing the error in the console, and you're going to keep getting errors until you fix it.

Comment: Where is this console you're using to test the code? Also i'm not sure if using jsfiddle was the best way to ask this question.  I looked through mausdb.js and I don't see where the zero-width space is.  The file worked fine before I added the new `fill()` function.  Can we focus more on the logic of my function?

Comment: I simply download that .js file from the URL in your jsfiddle and look at a hex dump of its contents.  Just edit it in a safe text editor, delete the last line of that function, and re-type them, then re-upload the file to its server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8133/discussion-between-hopup-and-pointy)